# Xcode 10 code completion placeholders — what is the "T"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, code-completion

In Xcode 10 code completion, the text underlying the placeholder tokens has an extra `#T#` before it (to see that this is so, copy and paste the inserted code template into a different text editor):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: <#T##String?#>, message: <#T##String?#>, 
    preferredStyle: <#T##UIAlertController.Style#>)
```

What is that? Does "T" mean Type? What difference does it make in my usage of the placeholder?

Comment: Just to note that the exact same thing is true for Xcode 9.4 placeholders...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax `<#T##_A_##_B_#>` is used to specify a default piece of code for the placeholder. The placeholder will be displayed as `_A_`,  but when the user presses the enter key the placeholder will be replaced with `_B_`.

Placeholder:

[image]

After pressing enter:

[image]

It'd a useful feature when presenting something to an audience, because as opposed to snippets, I would't need to remember the name of each snippet, I'd just select a placeholder and press enter to get the right piece of code.

**EDIT**:

Answering your question, indeed it seems that the T refers to type. If you try to replace the placeholder with an expression, like `<#T##Example1##let i = 3#>`, the placeholder it's not replaced with `let i = 3` as you would expect. It is instead replaced with `<<error type>>`.

Furthermore, this placeholder `<#T##transform: (Error) throws -> U?##(Error) throws -> U?#>` is replaced with:

```
{ (<#Error#>) -> U? in
    <#code#>
}
```

My guess is that when you prepend the `T` you are telling Xcode that you will provide a type, then Xcode finds an appropriate default value for that type.

Comment: I found no reference to this, I figured it out by copying some of the placeholders that appear with autocomplete.

Comment: the syntax is referenced in the [playground documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift-playgrounds/specifying-editable-regions-in-a-playground-page)

Answer (score 2):

The `T` Refers to the [Typed Placeholder Tokens](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift-playgrounds/specifying-editable-regions-in-a-playground-page#Mark-Editable-Areas-with-Placeholder-Tokens) and works mostly when the editor can show some input views (like in the playground)

for example, `<#T##number of llamas##Int#>` represents that:

- This placeholder is `T`yped
- The name of the input is `number of llamas`
- The type of the input would be an `Int`eger

So selecting the placeholder opens the number-entry popover.

Since it's about suggesting inputs, you can't see the true benefits in Environments like Xcode where you are using a physical keyboard on your mac. But it become very handy when you use for example an iPad.